# Change simulator stage model configurations in runtime

Tags: simulation, stage

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can I change the stage/stageros robot models properties in runtime wihtout restarting the stage simulator?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12384/change-simulator-stage-model-configurations-in-runtime/) by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2982 on 2011-12-17

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) on 2011-12-20**:
The attatched patch in my own answer is a solution for the problem itsef. As Perco suggested I requested this enhacement. I only focused on laser config so this patch can be improved. Almost any aspect of Stage can be reconfigured in runtime using this template - Bridge ros-service C++Stage API

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2011-12-20**:
@Pablo Iñigo Blasco : I am using Stage (as Player/Stage and also as ROS/stageros) for about 2 years now, I am very apprehensive of any solution to your problem. I follow your question most keenly.

**Comment by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) on 2011-12-17**:
I've refactored the entry to clarify what is the question and what is the answer.

**Comment by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) on 2011-12-17**:
Currently there is no support for this feature. Maybe somebdoy need it. Here you also can find the answer about how to solve the problem.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2011-12-17**:
Is this a question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is not currently supported.

However here you can find a partial solution.

Here I attached a patch over the stage package which provides a service to change elemental attributes of lasers beams of the robot models. This service can be also a template for further runtime configuration changes.

Example:

```
import roslib
roslib.load_manifest('stage')
import rospy
import stage.msg
import stage.srv
stage_model_config_srv=rospy.ServiceProxy('/stageros/set_models_configurations',stage.srv.SetModelConfig)

model_config=stage.msg.ModelConfig()
model_config.laser_fov=-1.0
model_config.laser_range_max=-1
model_config.laser_range_min=-1
model_config.laser_resolution=-1
model_config.laser_samples=8
stage_model_config_srv(models_configurations=[model_config])
```

It was useful for some test bencharks in my research and maybe will be useful for someone else.

But the below diff text is a good resume of the changes made. However the attached patch (rename from it to .diff) [C:\fakepath\stage_configuration_service.diff.jpg](https://ftp.osuosl.org/pub/ros/download.ros.org/downloads/se_migration/ros/1324140533544584.jpg) should be used. It is a bit more verbose (a lot of indentation eclipse-ros format changes)

This patch have been applied over:

```
URL: https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/stage/trunk
Repository Root: https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg
Repository UUID: eb33c2ac-9c88-4c90-87e0-44a10359b0c3
Revision: 38364
```

Diff text:

```
Index: msg/ModelConfig.msg
===================================================================
--- msg/ModelConfig.msg (revision 0)
+++ msg/ModelConfig.msg (revision 0)
@@ -0,0 +1,8 @@
+#geometry_msgs/Pose2D laser_pose
+#to maintiain its current value set each config property to -1 
+
+int32 laser_samples
+int32 laser_resolution
+float64 laser_fov
+int32 laser_range_max
+int32 laser_range_min
Index: src/stageros.cpp
===================================================================
--- src/stageros.cpp    (revision 38364)
+++ src/stageros.cpp    (working copy)
@@ -47,6 +47,7 @@
 #include 
 
 #include "tf/transform_broadcaster.h"
+#include "stage/SetModelConfig.h"
 
 #define USAGE "stageros "
 #define ODOM "odom"
@@ -79,6 +80,9 @@
     std::vector cmdvel_subs_;
     ros::Publisher clock_pub_;
 
+    ros::ServiceServer models_configurations_service_;
+    bool model_config_callback(stage::SetModelConfig::Request& request, stage::SetModelConfig::Response& response);
+
     // A helper function that is executed for each stage model.  We use it
     // to search for models of interest.
     static void ghfunc(Stg::Model* mod, StageNode* node);
@@ -213,9 +217,47 @@
   this->laserMsgs = new sensor_msgs::LaserScan[numRobots];
   this->odomMsgs = new nav_msgs::Odometry[numRobots];
   this->groundTruthMsgs = new nav_msgs::Odometry[numRobots];
+
+  this->models_configurations_service_ = localn.advertiseService("set_models_configurations", &StageNode::model_config_callback, this);
 }
 
+bool StageNode::model_config_callback(stage::SetModelConfig::Request& request, stage::SetModelConfig::Response& response)
+{
+  boost::mutex::scoped_lock lock(msg_lock);
 
+  if(request.models_configurations.size()>lasermodels.size())
+  {
+    ROS_ERROR("Service stage model config: configurations.count > simulator_models.count");
+    return false;
+  }
+
+  for(unsigned int i=0;ilasermodels[i]->GetConfig();
+    if(current_msg_config.laser_samples!=-1)
+      laser_config.sample_count=current_msg_config.laser_samples; ///SetConfig(laser_config);
+  }
+
+  return true;
+}
+
 // Subscribe to models of interest.  Currently, we find and subscribe
 // to the first 'laser' model and the first 'position' model.  Returns
 // 0 on success (both models subscribed), -1 otherwise.

Index: srv/SetModelConfig.srv
===================================================================
--- srv/SetModelConfig.srv  (revision 0)
+++ srv/SetModelConfig.srv  (revision 0)
@@ -0,0 +1,2 @@
+ModelConfig[] models_configurations
+---
\ No newline at end of file
Index: CMakeLists.txt
===================================================================
--- CMakeLists.txt  (revision 38364)
+++ CMakeLists.txt  (working copy)
@@ -22,6 +22,9 @@
 include_directories(${STAGE_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/Stage-3.2)
 link_directories(${STAGE_LIBRARY_DIRS} ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)
 
+rosbuild_genmsg()
+rosbuild_gensrv()
+
 rosbuild_add_executable(bin/stageros src/stageros.cpp)
 
 rosbuild_link_boost(bin/stageros thread)
```

---

Originally posted by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) with karma: 2982 on 2011-12-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pablo Iñigo Blasco](https://answers.ros.org/users/356/pablo-i%C3%B1igo-blasco/) on 2011-12-17**:
Done. https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/ticket/5307

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-12-17**:
I suggest you open an enhancement ticket against the stage package and attach the patch to that. That way, this patch won't get lost and may make it into a future release of the stage package. Please update your answer to include that trac link once you create the ticket.